# Greenplum (Pg 8.2 based) -- Function that performs 3 statements

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, greenplum

I'm using Greenplum and I just want to create a function that performs 1 truncate and 2 selects. This is what I have but it is not working

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.pe_GP3()
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$     
Begin 
truncate table public.pe_new;
select public.peGP();
select public.peGP2();
END;
$function$
```

Comment: What should happen with the results of the select statements? (Besides 8.2 is outdated and un-maintained, you should really, really upgrade to 9.x as now)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am on GreenPlum so upgrading is impossible. One of the select statements inserts into a table, the other one updates a row in that table. I don't need any results being outputted. I just need those 3 queries to run all in one function.

Comment: Then you need to use `perform` not `select`: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-NORESULT

Comment: @precose If you're on Greenplum you are not on PostgreSQL 8.2. Fixing title. Please clearly indicate that you're asking about Greenplum. It might report PostgreSQL 8.2 as its `version()`, but that's only for driver compatibility.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It seems your comment should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes I agree. I do not know how to accept a comment though.

Comment: @precose: You cannot. That's why I addressed a_horse to post his comment as answer.